# How to load entire webpage in android's webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load complete webpage in webview without the scrollbars.
The user should be able to zoom in. I am using:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings( ).setSupportZoom( true );      
mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

but it doesn't have any effect on the webpage. I have to scroll through in order to view the contents of the page which are not displayed on the webview. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below settings:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Thanks, 
Pop